# to pass data is more sequential way

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have five input fields as

- I_ADDR_LINE_1
- I_ADDR_LINE_2
- I_ADDR_LINE_3
- I_ADDR_LINE_4
- I_ADDR_LINE_5

there can be data in them or not
there can be data in line 2 and 4
there are 5 records 
example :If data is coming in line 2 and line 4 then we have to send in line output line 1 and line 2

I have made 5 variable ports with flag 1 and 0
1 if data is there
0 if no data is there in that line

code I have used in one variable port for I_ADDR_LINE_1

```
IIF(
NOT ISNULL(I_ADDR_LINE_1_TX)
AND 
NOT IS_SPACES(I_ADDR_LINE_1_TX)
AND 
LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(I_ADDR_LINE_1_TX)))<>0,1,0
)
```

Now if data is coming in rows 1,3,5 in output data should go sequentially i.e in row 1,2,3

Comment: can you give an example what is your input and what output to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, I_ADDR_LINE_1, I_ADDR_LINE_2, I_ADDR_LINE_3, I_ADDR_LINE_4,I_ADDR_LINE_5 are columns in your input file/table. If you receive data for I_ADDR_LINE_1, I_ADDR_LINE_3 & I_ADDR_LINE_5 in your inpur file, you want to load it as I_ADDR_LINE_1,I_ADDR_LINE_2 & I_ADDR_LINE_3 in the output.

Assuming my understanding is correct as mentioned above, the variable port logic you defined looks good and you should create 4 more variable ports for ADDR_LINE 2, 3,4 & 5 with flag values as 1/0. Finally you should try to identify to load this sequentially in the output. In the output variable, you should try to identify the sequence based on nested if else statement as mentioned below.

```
OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_1 = 

IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_1=1,I_ADDR_LINE_1,
(IIF(var_I_ADDR_LINE_2=1,I_ADDR_LINE_2,
(IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_3=1,I_ADDR_LINE_3,
(IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_4=1,I_ADDR_LINE_4,
IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_5=1,I_ADDR_LINE_5,
NULL)))))))) 

OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_2

IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_2=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_1 <> I_ADDR_LINE_2),I_ADDR_LINE_2,
(IIF(var_I_ADDR_LINE_3=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_1 <> I_ADDR_LINE_3),I_ADDR_LINE_3,
(IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_4=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_1 <> I_ADDR_LINE_4),I_ADDR_LINE_4,
(IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_5=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_1 <> I_ADDR_LINE_5),I_ADDR_LINE_5,
NULL))))))))))) -- 4


OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_3

IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_3=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_2 <> I_ADDR_LINE_3),I_ADDR_LINE_3,
(IIF(var_I_ADDR_LINE_4=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_2 <> I_ADDR_LINE_4),I_ADDR_LINE_4,
(IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_5=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_2 <> I_ADDR_LINE_4),I_ADDR_LINE_5,
NULL))))))))



OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_4

IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_4=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_3 <> I_ADDR_LINE_4),I_ADDR_LINE_4,
(IIF(var_I_ADDR_LINE_5=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_3 <> I_ADDR_LINE_5),I_ADDR_LINE_5,
NULL)))))

OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_5

IIF(VAR_I_ADDR_LINE_5=1,(IIF(OUT_VAR_ADDR_LINE_4 <> I_ADDR_LINE_5),I_ADDR_LINE_5,
NULL))
```

Comment: Your understanding is absolutely correct ,but i am not able to get the desired result using code you have suggested

Comment: @Abhinavmittal... You shall give it a try, share the results and indicate the error you're getting. Sarath put a great effort into preparing an answer for your problem, don't expect this user to now guess what kind of issues you're having. Help others help you!

Answer (score 0):

### Sorry that it didn't work. I'm not working in Informatica anymore. So i haven't tried that code. It was just a prototype to give you an idea. Instead of implementing this is a informatica you have other ways as well. Just use informatica to do a one to one load from source to target and then write a query on your database. Again i'm not sure if you are using a database in your project. I have written the below queries which has four levels of sub-query in Netezza. At each subquery layer, we try to load the values sequentially.  Please find below query and test result on sample data.

--- Data in source

```
select * from test1234;
```

ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | ID5
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
     |     |   3 |   4 |   5

---

Output from the below query. SRC_* attributes represent source data, TGT_* attributes represent the target data. Hope it helps

SRC_ID1 | SRC_ID2 | SRC_ID3 | SRC_ID4 | SRC_ID5 | VAR_ID1 | VAR_ID2 | VAR_ID3 | VAR_ID4 | VAR_ID5 | TGT_ID1 | IGT_ID2 | TGT_ID3 | TGT_ID4 | TGT_ID5
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
         |         |       3 |       4 |       5 |       0 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |       3 |       4 |       5 |         |
(1 row)

```
select 
e.ID1 AS SRC_ID1,
e.ID2 AS SRC_ID2,
e.ID3 AS SRC_ID3,
e.ID4 AS SRC_ID4,
e.ID5 AS SRC_ID5,
e.col1 AS VAR_ID1,
e.col2 AS VAR_ID2,
e.col3 AS VAR_ID3,
e.col4 AS VAR_ID4,
e.col5 AS VAR_ID5,
e.abc as TGT_ID1,
e.def AS IGT_ID2,
e.ghi AS TGT_ID3,
e.jkl AS TGT_ID4,      
(case when e.col5=1 and e.abc <> e.id5 and e.def <> e.id5 and e.ghi <> e.id5 and e.id5 <> e.jkl then e.id5 
else null end)as TGT_ID5
from (     
select d.abc,
       d.def,
       d.ghi,              
(case when d.col4=1 and d.abc <> d.id4 and d.def <> d.id4 and d.ghi <> d.id4 then d.id4  
when d.col5=1 and d.abc <> d.id5 and d.def <> d.id5 and d.ghi <> d.id5 then d.id5 
else null 
end)  as jkl,
d.col1,
d.col2,
d.col3,
d.col4,
d.col5,
d.ID1,
d.ID2,
d.ID3,
d.ID4,
d.ID5       
from
(select c.abc,
       c.def,  
(case when c.col3=1 and c.abc <> c.id3 and c.def <> c.id3  then c.id3  
when c.col4=1 and c.abc <> c.id4 and c.def <> c.id4 then c.id4  
when c.col5=1 and c.abc <> c.id5 and c.def <> c.id5 then c.id5 
else null 
end)  as ghi,
c.col1,
c.col2,
c.col3,
c.col4,
c.col5,
c.ID1,
c.ID2,
c.ID3,
c.ID4,
c.ID5       
from (
select b.abc,
(case when b.col2=1 and b.abc <> b.id2 then b.id2  
when b.col3=1 and b.abc <> b.id3 then b.id3  
when b.col4=1 and b.abc <> b.id4 then b.id4  
when b.col5=1 and b.abc <> b.id5 then b.id5 
else null 
end)  as def,
b.col1,
b.col2,
b.col3,
b.col4,
b.col5,
b.ID1,
b.ID2,
b.ID3,
b.ID4,
b.ID5         
from (
select 
(case when a.col1=1 then a.id1  
when a.col2=1 then a.id2  
when a.col3=1 then a.id3  
when a.col4=1 then a.id4  
when a.col5=1 then a.id5 else null 
end)  as abc,
a.*
 from 
(select (case when ID1 is null then 0 else 1 end) as col1,
       (case when ID2 is null then 0 else 1 end) as col2,
       (case when ID3 is null then 0 else 1 end) as col3,
       (case when ID4 is null then 0 else 1 end) as col4,
       (case when ID5 is null then 0 else 1 end) as col5,
       ID1,
       ID2,
       ID3,
       ID4,
       ID5 from test1234 ) a ) b ) c ) d ) e
```

Regards
Sharath

Comment: Sharath thanks for your help ,i just have to create one resuable transformation in Informatcia , the code you have suggested is working for some scenarios but it is breaking in certain scenarios

Comment: Cool. Thats great to hear :-) . Of-course I didn't test all the scenarios.